# Irreducible Markov chain. Pakes Lemma.

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I've got problem with that task:

> Consider $\{Z_n\}_{n>0}$ is iid with integer values with expected value $\mathbb EZ_1<0$ and $\{X_n\}_{n\ge0}$ is homogeneous Markov chain defined by 
>   $$ X_{n+1} = (X_n+Z_{n+1})_+$$$ n\ge1$,
>   where $X_0$ is stochastic independent with $\{Z_n\}$. Using Pakes Lemma show, that irreducible $\{X_n\}$ is positive recurrent.

I found the Lemma: http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~monmege/teach/probas/TD2.pdf, p.2. I showed that 
$$p_{ij} = \begin{cases}P(Z_1\le-i),  &\text{for } j=0\\P(Z_1=j-i),  &\text{else}\end{cases}$$
And 
$$\mathbb E[X_{n+1} \mid X_n=i] < \infty$$But I dont know how to show or start with limit:
$$\limsup_{i\to\infty}\mathbb E[X_{n+1}-X_n \mid X_n=i]<0$$

Comment: The first step is to write down each $\mathbb E[X_{n+1}-X_n | X_n=i]$ as $\mathbb E[v_i(Z)]$ where $Z$ is distributed as every $Z_n$, for some explicit functions $v_i$. Can you do that?

Comment: $$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\cdot P(X_{n+1}-X_n=k|X_n=i) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\cdot P(X_{n+1}=k+i|X_n=i) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\cdot P(Z=k) $$

But it wont be $\mathbb E[Z]$, because $Z \in \mathbb Z$

Hmm... I think i see now i

Comment: No i dont see...

Comment: Maybe problem is in my def of $p_{i j}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly observe that \begin{align}\left(X_{n+1}-X_n \mid X_n=i\right)&=\left(\left( i+Z_{n+1}\right)_+-i\right)\\[0.2cm]&=\begin{cases}i+Z_{n+1}-i,& \text{if }Z_{n+1}+i\ge 0\\0-i,& \text{if }Z_{n+1}+i< 0\end{cases}\\[0.3cm]&=\begin{cases}Z_{n+1},& \text{if }Z_{n+1}\ge -i\\-i,& \text{if }Z_{n+1}<-i \end{cases}=\max{\{-i,Z_{n+1}\}}\end{align} Hence, $$\Bbb E[X_{n+1}-X_n \mid X_n=i]=\Bbb E\left[\max{\{-i, Z_{n+1}\}}\right]=\Bbb E\left[\max{\{-i, Z_1\}}\right]$$ where the last equality is true, since the $Z_n$'s are iid. Now, we will take the $\limsup$ of the this expression and we will interchange the order of $\limsup$ and $\Bbb E$ with the [Reverse Fatou Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Reverse_Fatou_lemma) (RFL) to conclude:

\begin{align}\limsup_{i \to +\infty}\Bbb E\left[\max{\{-i, Z_1\}}\right]\overset{\text{(RFL)}}\le  \Bbb E\left[\limsup_{i\to +\infty}\left(\max{\{-i, Z_1\}}\right)\right]&=\Bbb E[\max{\{-\infty,Z_1\}}]\\[0.2cm]&=\Bbb E[Z_1]<0\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

$$X_{n+1}-X_n = ((X_n+Z_{n+1})\vee 0)-X_n=Z_{n+1}\vee (-X_n) \Rightarrow$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}-X_n\mid X_n=i]=\mathbb{E}[Z_{n+1}\vee (-i)]=\mathbb{E}[Z_1\vee (-i)]\to \mathbb{E}Z_1<0$$

as $i\to \infty$ (assuming that $Z_1\in L^1$).